# app color independent of windows mode (dark)

Tags: .net, xaml

I have a c# wpf app(.Net framework 4.7.2) that automatically changes the colors according to the mode dark, light, defined in the windows settings. However, not all elements seem to be compatible with it, which means that I have, for example, white text on a white background.

how can i set the program to always run in light mode?

fixed background color does not solve the problem because the text colors etc. are also changed. in the settings and in the xmal, I didn't manage it either